# Boost.Python failing to resolve derived type passed to function

Tags: python, c++, boost, boost-python

I've run into yet another snag in my Boost.Python adventure.

I have the following Python module defined:

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/python.hpp>

using namespace boost;
using namespace boost::python;

struct Base { };

void foo(boost::shared_ptr<Base>)
{
    std::cout << "yay\n";
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(Test)
{
    class_<Base, shared_ptr<Base>, noncopyable>("Base", init<>());

    def("foo", foo);
}
```

Running the following script:

```
from Test import *

class Bar(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

foo(Base()) #works
foo(Bar()) #error
```

The last line yields an error to the effect of this:

```
Python argument types in
    foo(Bar)
did not match C++ signature:
    foo(class boost::shared_ptr<struct Base>)
```

Now my question is why doesn't this work? Surely the type system should be able to work out the `Bar` is a `Base` instance?

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/43f111fb3032a20a

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this particular case, the error message is misleading.  The function receives an argument with the right *type*; however, the argument has an inappropriate *value*.  The `Bar` initializer is not initializing the Python `Base` part of its hierarchy.  The Python instance does not contain a `boost::shared_ptr<Base>` instance, resulting in Boost.Python failing to dispatch to the C++ function:

```python
class Bar(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        pass # Base is not initialized.

fun(Base()) # No boost::shared_ptr<Base> instance.
```

To resolve the issue, explicitly invoke `Base.__init__()` within `Bar.__init__()`:

```python
class Bar(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        Base.__init__(self) # Instantiates boost::shared_ptr<Base>.

fun(Bar()) # Boost.Python will extract boost::shared_ptr<Base> from Bar().
```

---

For details, in Python if a derived class defines an `__init__()` method, then it should explicitly invoke the parent class' `__init__()` method.  The Python documentation [states](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__):

> If a base class has an `__init__()` method, the derived class’s `__init__()` method, if any, must explicitly call it to ensure proper initialization of the base class part of the instance; for example: `BaseClass.__init__(self, [args...])`.

In Boost.Python, C++ class wrappers have an [`instance_holder`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/python/doc/v2/instance_holder.html#instance_holder-spec).  These objects hold C++ instances within their Python object wrapper, and instantiation of the C++ object occurs within the Python object's `__init__` function:

> When an `__init__` function for a wrapped C++ class is invoked, a new  `instance_holder` instance is created and installed in the Python object [...]

Therefore, if the Python object's `__init__()` method is not invoked, the internal C++ object will not be instantiated.  When an exposed C++ function is invoked from Python, Boost.Python will examine the invocation arguments, attempting to identify a matching C++ function within a set of exposed functions.  When no match is found, it will raise a `Boost.Python.ArgumentError` exception, listing the argument types and the set of C++ functions for which it failed to match.

---

Here is a complete example [demonstrating](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8da3db1c6530e828) having two different Python types inherit from an exposed C++ type, where one hierarchy is initialized properly and the other is not:

```cpp
#include <boost/python.hpp>

struct base {};

void foo(boost::shared_ptr<base>) {}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
  namespace python = boost::python;
  python::class_<base, boost::shared_ptr<base>, boost::noncopyable>(
      "Base", python::init<>())
    ;

  python::def("foo", &foo);
}
```

Interactive usage:

```python
>>> import example
>>> class GoodDerived(example.Base):
...     def __init__(self):
...         example.Base.__init__(self)
...
>>> class BadDerived(example.Base):
...     def __init__(self):
...         pass
...
>>> assert(isinstance(GoodDerived(), example.Base))
>>> assert(isinstance(BadDerived(), example.Base))
>>> try:
...     example.foo(GoodDerived())
...     got_exception = False
... except:
...     got_exception = True
... finally:
...     assert(not got_exception)
...
>>> try:
...     example.foo(BadDerived())
...     got_exception = False
... except:
...     got_exception = True
... finally:
...     assert(got_exception)
```

Note that while the type hierarchy is correct and verifiable via `isinstance(()`, the types do not indicate if an instance has an appropriate value.

Comment: I will try this when I get back at my computer!